# Auto Login to a website using powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

[image]I am getting following error message when i am running my powershell script

```
The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\Test.ps1:17 char:1
+ $usernamefield.value = $username
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\Test.ps1:20 char:1
+ $passwordfield.value = $password
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

Method invocation failed because [System.DBNull] does not contain a method named 'click'.
At C:\Test.ps1:23 char:1
+ $Link.click()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound`
```

**My script:**

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true # Make it visible

$usernmae="test"

$password="test1"

$ie.Navigate("https://website.com/login")

While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}

$usernamefield = $ie.document.getElementByID('ysi_email')
$usernamefield.value = $username

$passwordfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('ysi_password')
$passwordfield.value = $password

$Link = $ie.document.getElementByID('ysi_btn_login')
$Link.click()
```

I cant seem to understand the problem here, i have looked into other examples within stackoverflow but i still cant find the problem.

The same id works fine in another example in a python script.

Here is a screenshot [image: Edit: Providing screenshot of the elements]

Comment: if you set like this, same problem? $ie.document.getElementByID('ysi_email').value = $username

Comment: are you sur id name is 'ysi_email'?

Comment: Yes, please have a look at the attached screenshot. This id works with python and chrome but isnt working with powershell & IE ?

Comment: i get this when i try $ie.document.getElementByID('ysi_email').value = $username  `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:16 char:1
+ $ie.document.getElementByID('ysi_email').value = $username
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull`

Comment: Line 4 has a typo.

Answer (score 6):

The problem comes from the fact that object of IDs `'ysi_email'`, `'ysi_password'` and  `'ysi_btn_login'` are not found in the DOM of the document loaded at `https://website.com/login`.

To solve your trouble load your document in Chrome, or Firerfox or Explorer with the developpers tools activated (Press F12) and *inspect* the objects you want to find.

[image]

---

Here is a working solution according to your comments :

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true # Make it visible

$username="test@toto.fr"

$password="test1"

$ie.Navigate("https://To your detailled URL")

While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}

$usernamefield = $ie.document.getElementByID('ysi_email')
$usernamefield.value = "$username"

$passwordfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('ysi_password')
$passwordfield.value = "$password"

$Link = $ie.document.getElementByID('ysi_btn_login')
$Link.click()

$ie.Quit()
```

---

Here you can see the result for me.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Sorry just trying to understand this, would DOM be different in IE and chrome? The python script is basically calling the chrome whereas in powershell i am calling IE ?

Comment: Thanks. I understand and that's why i am looking for some help here.

Comment: @irish, I adapt my answer, as soon as you ask me I'll remove your URL from the answer and the comments.

Comment: Thanks @JPBlanc, you may remove the url now. I have tried getting it by Name but even that throws the same error. I am stuck with this.

Comment: @irish I don't understand, the code I use in my answer works for me.

Comment: Hmm that's strange because it didn't make a difference for me. I have literally copied your code but all it does is opens the login page. It doesnt even fill in the login fields.... Is your IE version 11?

Comment: I add the picture with this url `https://fr.hightail.com/loginSpaces?redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Fspaces.hightail.com%2Foauth%2Fhightail`

Comment: I have used this exact url in the code but the page that opens up says the link you have provided is invalid. Have attached the screenshot

Comment: Same here, doesn't work which is odd, it should. I read there's an IE11 and ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application', I ended up using  Selenium and it works fine.

Comment: I'am also using Selenium with PowerShell using Nuget  packages, but I sometime met troubles with Chrome drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck for a while with this with IE11 and the native COM methods, I was facing the same problem, there must be some sort of bug, but Selenium with IE11 worked for me, just had to import the .dll and the IE driver, the syntax was similar enough for me to get a hang of it and get what I needed. For whatever reason, selenium found the elements while the native IE COM never did. Also, you can use Chrome or Firefox.

Sample code:

```
#Load Selenium to download all URL xml sites
Add-Type -Path "C:\Temp\WebDriver.dll" # Load the Selenium .Net library
$env:PATH += ";C:\Temp" # Load the IEDriverServer.exe from a path where it is stored
$ie_object = New-Object "OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver" # Instantiate Internet Explorer

# Using Element ID for this example, but I prefer using The Name element.
$ie_object.Navigate().GoToURL( "https://website.com/login") # Navigate to login page URL
$InputUser = $ie_object.FindElementById("ysi_email") # Find the ID element for username input textbox, gt this from the DOM developer Tools search
$InputUser.SendKeys("usernamegoeshere") # Push the text
$PasswordUser = $ie_object.FindElementById("ysi_password") # Find the ID element for password input textbox, get this from the DOM developer Tools search
$PasswordUser.SendKeys("passwordgoeshere") # Push the text
$LoginButton = $ie_object.FindElementById("ysi_btn_login") # Find the ID element for the submit button, get this from the DOM developer Tools search
$LoginButton.Click() #Sent click to the submit button
```

Get Selenium from: https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Thanks to newspaint, more info: 
https://newspaint.wordpress.com/2017/03/23/using-powershell-2-0-with-selenium-to-automate-internet-explorer-firefox-and-chrome/

Answer (score 1):

I am using PS 5.1 and Edge browser, and the above mentioned solution was not fully working as the `$Link` object did not contain `Click` Method. However, using the `Submit()` method did work. So basically in my case I had to change the next to last line to `$Link.Submit()`