# PowerShell throws error saying Click() does not exist

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, click

I'm practicing using PowerShell, and today I thought I'd write a script that logs me into a website. I have no use for this specific example, but I thought it would be good practice. I created it while referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624990/auto-login-to-a-website-using-powershell). Here is what I have so far.

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Visible = $true

$username = "my@email"
$password = "password"

$ie.Navigate("https://squirrel.ws/login")

While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}

$usernameField = $ie.Document.getElementByID('UserEmail')
$usernameField.value = $username

$passwordField = $ie.Document.getElementByID('UserPassword')
$passwordField.value = $password

$link = $ie.Document.getElementByID('$0')
$link.click()

$ie.Quit()
```

When I run this, an IE window appears, and almost immediately closes with this error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.DBNull] does not contain a method named 'click'.
At J:\removingForPrivacy\test.ps1 char:1
+ $link.click()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

So I'm pretty sure it throws an error either when trying to click, or because I labeled the button incorrectly, or both. When trying to create this, I couldn't find an ID for the button so I used what I could find. Otherwise I'm not sure why `click()` doesn't exist when it's in all the examples I'm seeing. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue came from the fact that when creating `$Link`, that I was using the wrong tags. I used all the same code, but swapped out the `$Link` creating line for:

```
$Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("button") | where-object {$_.type -eq "submit"}
```